# How can we enable a disabled item in a listbox in gwt?

Tags: gwt, listbox

To disable an item in a listbox I use the given code.

```
((Element) list.getElement().getChild(index).getChild(index)).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

But I need to enable that item again.What can be the solution .Please help me to sort out the problem.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "removeAttribute" will work:

```
((Element) list.getElement().getChild(index).getChild(index)).removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any one

Use 'GWT JSNI` (disable 0th option)

```
    final ListBox lb = new ListBox(); 
    lb.addItem("foo");
    lb.addItem("bar");
    lb.addItem("baz");
    lb.addItem("toto");
    lb.addItem("tintin");
    disableSelectOption(lb.getElement(), 0);

...

public static native void disableSelectOption(Element listElement, int index) /*-{
    listElement.options[index].disabled = true;
}-*/;
```

OR

Use `setAttribute` (disable 0th option)

```
    ((Element)lb.getElement().getChild(0)).setAttribute("disabled", "");
```